# Update component state when props change

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a carousel component that receives the carousel items as a prop. I'm storing the currently active carousel item in the state of the carousel component. The carousel itself is a slider and controlled with a GSAP draggable. The number of carousel items might change, and then I want to reset the state so that the first item is active. How can I achieve this with the current React version? I tried:

```
static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state) {
  if (state.openItem > props.items.length) {
    return {
      openItem: 0,
    };
  }
  return null;
}
```

But this will only reset if the current item is larger than the total number of items. I would like a way where I could compare the prevProps so that I can check if the total number of items have changed. If I set the state in componentDidUpdate, that might cause an endless render loop. I don't want to pull out the state to the parent component, because that would make the parent require too much functionality for the carousel component to be reusable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store `items` in state and then use `getDerivedStateFromProps` like this :

```
static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState) {
  if (nextProps.items.length !== prevState.items.length) {
    return {
      openItem: 0,
      items: nextProps.items
    };
  }
  return null;
}
```

This is fine for the requirement but ideally you should figure out a way to check for content equality of the `items` and then fire the state change. You can use `isEqual` from `lodash` like this and replace equality check with :

```
if (_.isEqual(nextProps.items.length, prevState.items.length))
```

*note that `isEqual` performs deep equality checks and may have performance implications.

Comment: Thanks, I actually came up with a similar solution in the meantime. I'm passing a hash of the objects into the component from the outside, which I set inside the state. Then in getDerivedStateFromProps I compare the new hash to the old one in the state. If they don't match, I reset the openItem.

Comment: But doesn't sending hash from outside adds extra responsibility to the consumer of the carousel?

Comment: yeah, youre right, better to compute this inside the component.

Comment: i did it like this because i was passing actual components as props, so i wasn't certain if hashing those would still give the same hashes when the data was the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the getSnapshotBeforeUpdate() method for the compare the prevProps so that you can check if the total number of items have changed.

```
getSnapshotBeforeUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    // you can compare the previous prop value and previous state value as per you requirement
    if (prevProps.openItem.length > prevState.openItem.length) {
      // your code
    }
    return null;
  }
```

Comment: But then I would still have to go into componentDidUpdate and set the state there, right? At least that's what I see in the docs: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#getsnapshotbeforeupdate