# Which of these strategies is the best way to reset a component's state when the props change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a very simple component with a text field and a button:

[image: <image>]

It takes a list as input and allows the user to cycle through the list.

The component has the following code:

```
import * as React from "react";
import {Button} from "@material-ui/core";

interface Props {
    names: string[]
}
interface State {
    currentNameIndex: number
}

export class NameCarousel extends React.Component<Props, State> {

    constructor(props: Props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { currentNameIndex: 0}
    }

    render() {
        const name = this.props.names[this.state.currentNameIndex].toUpperCase()
        return (
            <div>
                {name}
                <Button onClick={this.nextName.bind(this)}>Next</Button>
            </div>
        )
    }

    private nextName(): void {
        this.setState( (state, props) => {
            return {
                currentNameIndex: (state.currentNameIndex + 1) % props.names.length
            }
        })
    }
}
```

This component works great, except **I have not handled the case when the state changes.**  When the 
state changes, I would like to reset the `currentNameIndex` to zero.

What is the best way to do this?

---

Options I have conciderred:

### Using `componentDidUpdate`

This solution is ackward, because `componentDidUpdate` runs after render, so I need to add a clause
in the render method to "do nothing" while the component is in an invalid state, if I am not careful,
I can cause a null-pointer-exception.

I have included an implementation of this below.

### Using `getDerivedStateFromProps`

The `getDerivedStateFromProps` method is `static` and the signature only gives you access to the 
current state and next props.  This is a problem because you cannot tell if the props have changed.  As
a result, this forces you to copy the props into the state so that you can check if they are the same.

### Making the component "fully controlled"

I don't want to do this.  This component should privately own what the currently selected index is.

### Making the component "fully uncontrolled with a key"

I am considering this approach, but don't like how it causes the parent to need to understand the 
implementation details of the child.

[Link](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html#recommendation-fully-uncontrolled-component-with-a-key)

---

### Misc

I have spent a great deal of time reading [You Probably Don't Need Derived State](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html#recommendation-fully-uncontrolled-component-with-a-key)
but am largely unhappy with the solutions proposed there.

I know that variations of this question have been asked multiple times, but I don't feel like any of the answers weigh the possible solutions.  Some examples of duplicates:

- [How to reset state in a component on prop change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59343481/how-to-reset-state-in-a-component-on-prop-change)
- [Update component state when props change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54441229/update-component-state-when-props-change)

  - [Updating state on props change in React Form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32414308/updating-state-on-props-change-in-react-form)

---

## Appendix

Solution using `componetDidUpdate` (see description above)

```
import * as React from "react";
import {Button} from "@material-ui/core";

interface Props {
    names: string[]
}
interface State {
    currentNameIndex: number
}

export class NameCarousel extends React.Component<Props, State> {

    constructor(props: Props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { currentNameIndex: 0}
    }

    render() {

        if(this.state.currentNameIndex >= this.props.names.length){
            return "Cannot render the component - after compoonentDidUpdate runs, everything will be fixed"
        }

        const name = this.props.names[this.state.currentNameIndex].toUpperCase()
        return (
            <div>
                {name}
                <Button onClick={this.nextName.bind(this)}>Next</Button>
            </div>
        )
    }

    private nextName(): void {
        this.setState( (state, props) => {
            return {
                currentNameIndex: (state.currentNameIndex + 1) % props.names.length
            }
        })
    }

    componentDidUpdate(prevProps: Readonly<Props>, prevState: Readonly<State>): void {
        if(prevProps.names !== this.props.names){
            this.setState({
                currentNameIndex: 0
            })
        }
    }

}
```

Solution using `getDerivedStateFromProps`:

```
import * as React from "react";
import {Button} from "@material-ui/core";

interface Props {
    names: string[]
}
interface State {
    currentNameIndex: number
    copyOfProps?: Props
}

export class NameCarousel extends React.Component<Props, State> {

    constructor(props: Props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { currentNameIndex: 0}
    }

    render() {

        const name = this.props.names[this.state.currentNameIndex].toUpperCase()
        return (
            <div>
                {name}
                <Button onClick={this.nextName.bind(this)}>Next</Button>
            </div>
        )
    }


    static getDerivedStateFromProps(props: Props, state: State): Partial<State> {

        if( state.copyOfProps && props.names !== state.copyOfProps.names){
            return {
                currentNameIndex: 0,
                copyOfProps: props
            }
        }

        return {
            copyOfProps: props
        }
    }

    private nextName(): void {
        this.setState( (state, props) => {
            return {
                currentNameIndex: (state.currentNameIndex + 1) % props.names.length
            }
        })
    }


}
```

Comment: Keep track of the relevant prop values in the state as well and use these to compare to the next props in the `getDerivedStateFromProps`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Updating state on props change in React Form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32414308/updating-state-on-props-change-in-react-form)

Comment: And exactly [the answer about `getDerivedStateFromProps`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49868300/1218980) since the other answers are a little outdated.

Comment: Why the component is getting the entire list of names when it's job is just displaying a single name? lift the state up and just pass the selected name as a prop and a function to update the `currentIndex`. When `names` are getting updated in the parent just reset `currentIndex`

Comment: @AsafAviv - The job of the component is to cycle through names.  Think of it as a `carousel` component or a name selector.

Comment: @EmileBergeron - I think that is currently my preferred solution but using `componentDidUpdate` is not completely terrible either.  Both are kind of bad.

Comment: I like @AsafAvivs solution: pass a function `next` to the component. The button displays the name, and its onClick just calls the next function, located in the parent, which handles the cycling

Comment: @DánielSomogyi - I am going to think more about this.  I was trying to delegate work to the component (the parent is already complex) but this is interesting...

Comment: Yea the `Carousel` component should hold the state of the carousel, the selected item should not care about any of this and follow the single responsibility principle which is in this case is just showing an item

Comment: @DánielSomogyi - I think I will have a similar issue in the parent......

Comment: @AsafAviv - I updated the code to make this more clear.

Comment: Can you include the parent component that holds the names?

Comment: @DánielSomogyi that just moves the problem to the parent, **unless** the parent is the component doing the async fetching which could know when to reset the state.

Comment: That's not an issue at all, the parent component sets the `names`, when it sets the `names` it also sets the `currentIndex` to 0

Comment: @AsafAviv it really depends on where the parent gets the `names` and if it makes sense for the parent to manage the logic of a carousel.

Comment: @EmileBergeron Agree and that's why i asked to include the parent component to see if names are used in other components as well

Comment: @EmileBergeron technically you are right, but i also think it makes sense to manage the currently shown name (or its index) in the same component, where the list of names get set. Of course that can blow up the parent(s), but you always can split  a component in smaller parts...

Comment: I am going to echo @AsafAviv's suggestion as it is a well proven approach to handling state in the component + Daniel Somogyi's latest comment for managing the index. I will point out that this component should not care how it gets 'names' as long as it is provided with it from a parent/application level. Do not overcomplicate yourself, if you were to extend this functionality with multiple components to handle their own states/data structures and even add redux, you will appreciate the simplicity and power of this approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you use a functional component?  Might simplify things a bit.

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Button } from "@material-ui/core";

interface Props {
    names: string[];
}

export const NameCarousel: React.FC<Props> = ({ names }) => {
  const [currentNameIndex, setCurrentNameIndex] = useState(0);

  const name = names[currentNameIndex].toUpperCase();

  useEffect(() => {
    setCurrentNameIndex(0);
  }, names);

  const handleButtonClick = () => {
    setCurrentIndex((currentNameIndex + 1) % names.length);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      {name}
      <Button onClick={handleButtonClick}>Next</Button>
    </div>
  )
};
```

`useEffect` is similar to `componentDidUpdate` where it will take an array of dependencies (state and prop variables) as the second argument.  When those variables change, the function in the first argument is executed.  Simple as that.  You can do additional logic checks inside of the function body to set variables (e.g., `setCurrentNameIndex`).

Just be careful if you have a dependency in the second argument that gets changed inside the function, then you will have infinite rerenders.

Check out the [useEffect docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html), but you'll probably never want to use a class component again after getting used to hooks.

Comment: This is a good answer.  Looks like it works due to the `useEffect`.  If you update to explain why this works, I will mark this as the accepted answer.

Comment: Check out the updated answer, let me know if you need more clarification.

Answer (score 4):

As i said in the comments, i'm not a fan of these solutions.

Components should not care what the parent is doing or what is the current `state` of the parent, they should simply take in `props` and output some `JSX`, this way they are truly reusable, composable and isolated which also makes testing a lot easier.

We can make the `NamesCarousel` component hold the names of the carousel together with the functionality of the carousel and the current visible name and make a `Name` component which does only one thing, display the name that comes in through `props`

To reset the `selectedIndex` when the items are changing add a [`useEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) with items as a dependency, although if you just add items to the end of the array you can ignore this part

```js
const Name = ({ name }) => <span>{name.toUpperCase()}</span>;

const NamesCarousel = ({ names }) => {
  const [selectedIndex, setSelectedIndex] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    setSelectedIndex(0)
  }, [names])// when names changes reset selectedIndex

  const next = () => {
    setSelectedIndex(prevIndex => prevIndex + 1);
  };

  const prev = () => {
    setSelectedIndex(prevIndex => prevIndex - 1);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={prev} disabled={selectedIndex === 0}>
        Prev
      </button>
      <Name name={names[selectedIndex]} />
      <button onClick={next} disabled={selectedIndex === names.length - 1}>
        Next
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Now this is fine but is the `NamesCarousel` reusable? no, the `Name` component is but the `Carousel` is coupled with the `Name` component.

**So what can we do to make it truly reusable and see the benefits of designing component in isolation**?

We can take advantage of the [render props](https://reactjs.org/docs/render-props.html) pattern.

Lets make a generic `Carousel` component which will take a generic list of `items` and invoke the `children` function passing in the selected `item`

```js
const Carousel = ({ items, children }) => {
  const [selectedIndex, setSelectedIndex] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    setSelectedIndex(0)
  }, [items])// when items changes reset selectedIndex

  const next = () => {
    setSelectedIndex(prevIndex => prevIndex + 1);
  };

  const prev = () => {
    setSelectedIndex(prevIndex => prevIndex - 1);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={prev} disabled={selectedIndex === 0}>
        Prev
      </button>
      {children(items[selectedIndex])}
      <button onClick={next} disabled={selectedIndex === items.length - 1}>
        Next
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

**Now what this pattern actually gives us?**

It gives us the ability to render the `Carousel` component like this

```js
// items can be an array of any shape you like
// and the children of the component will be a function 
// that will return the select item
<Carousel items={["Hi", "There", "Buddy"]}>
  {name => <Name name={name} />} // You can render any component here
</Carousel>
```

Now they are both isolated and truly reusable, you can pass `items` as an array of images, videos, or even users.

You can take it further and give the carousel the number of items you want to display as props and invoke the child function with an array of items

```js
return (
  <div>
    {children(items.slice(selectedIndex, selectedIndex + props.numOfItems))}
  </div>
)

// And now you will get an array of 2 names when you render the component
<Carousel items={["Hi", "There", "Buddy"]} numOfItems={2}>
  {names => names.map(name => <Name key={name} name={name} />)}
</Carousel>
```

Comment: I don't think that this will reset `selectedIndex` when the props change, will it?  If so, how?

Comment: @sixtyfootersdude currently no, i will update my answer in a sec.

Answer (score 1):

You ask what is the best option, the best option is to make it a Controlled component.

The component is too low in the hierarchy to know how to handle it's properties changing - what if the list changed but only slightly (perhaps adding a new name) - the calling component might want to keep the original position.

In all cases I can think about we are better off if the parent component can decide how the component should behave when provided a new list.

It's also likely that such a component is part of a bigger whole and needs to pass the current selection to it's parent - perhaps as part of a form.

If you are really adamant on not making it a controlled component, there are other options:

- Instead of an index you can keep the entire name (or an id component) in the state - and if that name no longer exists in the names list, return the first in the list. This is a slightly different behavior than your original requirements and might be a performance issue for a really really really long list, but it's very clean.
- If you are ok with hooks, than `useEffect` as Asaf Aviv suggested is a very clean way to do it.
- The "canonical" way to do it with classes seems to be `getDerivedStateFromProps` - and yes that means keeping a reference to the name list in the state and comparing it. It can look a bit better if you write it something like this:

```js
   static getDerivedStateFromProps(props: Props, state: State = {}): Partial<State> {

       if( state.names !== props.names){
           return {
               currentNameIndex: 0,
               names: props.names
           }
       }

       return null; // you can return null to signify no change.
   }
```

(you should probably use `state.names` in the render method as well if you choose this route)

But really - controlled component is the way to go, you'll probably do it sooner or later anyway when demands change and the parent needs to know the selected item.

Comment: While I disagree with: `The component is too low in the hierarchy to know how to handle it's properties changing`, this is the best answer.  The alternatives your provide are interesting and useful.  The primary reason I don't want to expose this prop is that this component will be used in multiple projects and I want the API to be minimal.

Comment: However one note: `If you are ok with hooks, than useEffect as Asaf Aviv suggested is a very clean way to do it.` - This does not solve the problem - despite having 4 votes, that question does not reset state on props-change.

Comment: `useEffect(() => {
    setSelectedIndex(0)
  }, [items])
`
UseEffect's second argument defines when it should run - so effectively it will run `setSelectedIndex(0)` whenever items change. Which is your requirement as far as I understand it.

Comment: @sixtyfootersdude the `useEffect` in my solution will reset the index when `names` changes, Tunn's `useEffect` is invalid and will show linting errors and will throw errors when names are changing.

Comment: Worth mentioning that if it doesn't reset for you, you are mutating `names` directly which is another issue.